# Is there any difference between installing from a burned .iso and installing from the decompressed .iso?

Tags: mount, iso-image, burning, virtual-drive

I have a .iso file which installs a program.

Do I need to burn it / mount it on a virtual drive? Or does decompressing it work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a program/piece of software, most likely not.  You should be able to extract the files from the image and run the necessary setup files.

For an OS, yes.  You will need to either burn it to a disc or use a utility like [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to write the image to a USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter.
I personally prefer mounting it as it's fastest and you don't have to deal with it manually.